# Laravel 4 - Eloquent query scope order

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

I'm currently having some troubles with Eloquent and how to order my query scopes.

My goal here is to get pages with comments and pages stored in a session variable. On the top of that, I also have a filter system to get pages of specific categories.

There are my two scopes:

```
public function scopeCategoryFilter($query, $filters = array())
{
    return !(empty($filters)) ?  $query->whereIn('page_type_code', $filters) : $query;
}


public function scopeInSession($query, $pages = array())
{
    return !empty($pages) ? $query->orWhereIn('code', $pages) : $query;
}
```

And my Eloquent request:

```
$pages = Page::has('Comments')
    ->InSession(Session::get('navigation.pagelist', []))
    ->CategoryFilter($filters)
    ->get();
```

I have no errors but the result is not what I expect.

This query returns me :

> (Posts having Comments) **OR** (Posts in session with given
>   Categories)

And i would like to have :

> (Posts having Comments OR in session)->With given Categories.

I think the problem is that the category filter is only apply on the pages returned by my *InSession* scope.

So i found a solution:

```
$pages = Page::has('Comments')
    ->CategoryFilter($filters)
    ->InSession(Session::get('navigation.pagelist', []))
    ->CategoryFilter($filters)
    ->get();
```

But I don't like using my CategoryFilter scope twice.

Do you have any idea how I could get the expected result without using my scope twice in the same Eloquent request? Maybe changing something in my scopes?

Thank you!

Comment: Shouldn't you reverse the order of the scopes in your query?
You call the InSession scope first, but this is the one containing the OR-WhereIn clause.

Comment: I tried, but if i call the Categoryfilter first, session pages are not filtered.

Comment: It's important to use get() instead of find().

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to wrap your `CategoryFilter` and `InSession` into another `where`, i think it will look like this:

```
$pages = Page::has('Comments')->where(function($query) use($filters) {
    return $query->InSession(Session::get('navigation.pagelist', []))
                 ->CategoryFilter($filters);
    })->get();
```

This should do the trick.

I've used this myself when searching for a user, searching on different fields, but i needed to exclude some users, and I did it like this:

```
public function scopeFindUser($query, $str, $alreadySelected) {
    return $query->where(function($query) use($str, $alreadySelected) {
        return $query->where('first_name', 'LIKE', "%" . $str . "%")
                     ->orWhere('last_name', 'LIKE', "%" . $str . "%")
                     ->orWhere('email', 'LIKE', "%" . $str . "%");
    })->whereNotIn('id', $alreadySelected);
}
```

Comment: Oh, thank you. I actually wraped has::('Comment') and the InSession filter in a where and then call the CategoryFilter. It works.